# Restoring a Truncated Table from a Backup

Tags: sql, database, oracle, import, constraints

I am restoring the data of a truncated table in an Oracle Database from an exported csv file. However, I find that the primary key auto-increments and does not insert the actual values of the primary key constrained column from the backed up file.

I intend to do the following:
1. drop the primary key 
2. import the table data
3. add primary key constraints on the required column

Is this a good approach? If not, what is recommended? Thanks.

EDIT: After more investigation, I observed there's a trigger to generate nextval on a sequence to be inserted into the primary key column. This is the source of the predicament. Hence, following the procedure above would not solve the problem. It lies in the trigger (and/or sequence) on the table. This is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following procedure to solve it:

```
drop trigger trigger_name
```

Imported the table data into target table

```
drop sequence sequence_name

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_NAME INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH start_index_for_next_val MAXVALUE max_val MINVALUE 1 NOCYCLECACHE 20 NOORDER

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "schema_name"."trigger_name"

before insert on target_table
for each row

begin
  select seq_name.nextval
  into :new.unique_column_name
  from dual;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

easier to use your .csv as an external table and then go

- create table your_table_temp as select * from external table
- examine the data in the new temp table to ensure you know what range of primary keys is present
- do a merge into the new table

samples from [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i.php) and [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement.php)

```
CREATE TABLE countries_ext (
  country_code      VARCHAR2(5),
  country_name      VARCHAR2(50),
  country_language  VARCHAR2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      country_code      CHAR(5),
      country_name      CHAR(50),
      country_language  CHAR(50)
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('Countries1.txt','Countries2.txt')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

and the merge

```
MERGE INTO employees e
    USING hr_records h
    ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, address)
    VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);
```

Edit: after you have merged the data you can drop the temp table and the result is your previous table with the old data and the new data together

Edit you mention " During imports, the primary key column does not insert from the file, but auto-increments".  This can only happen when there is a trigger on the table, likely, Before insert on each row.  Disable the trigger and then do your import. Re-enable the trigger after committing your inserts.

Comment: Thanks @kevinsky. Is there no way to restore while retaining use of the old table?

Comment: Seen your update @kevinsky. Looks like a good idea. Attempting it now. Will get update if it works.

Comment: Okay. It seems I misunderstand you, or you, me. First of all, there's only one column with the unique constraint. There's no new data, just the data to restore. During imports, the primary key column does not insert from the file, but auto-increments. My intention is to insert data into the unique column from file. Basically I want the DB engine to trust my inserts into this column. Your method @kevinsky does not solve my problem.